# Pyspark DataFrame: find difference between two DataFrames (values and column names)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having total 100+ columns in dataframe.
I am trying to compare two data frame and find unmatched record with column name.
I got a output bellow code but When I run the code for 100+ columns job got aborted.

I am doing this for SCD Type 2 delta process error finding.

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

d2 = sc.parallelize([("A1", 500,1005) ,("A2", 700,10007)])
dataFrame1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(d2, ["ID", "VALUE1", "VALUE2"])

d2 = sc.parallelize([("A1", 600,1005),("A2", 700,10007)])
dataFrame2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(d2, ["ID", "VALUE1", "VALUE2"])

key_id_col_name="ID"
key_id_value="A1"
dataFrame1.select("ID","VALUE1").subtract(dataFrame2.select("ID",col("VALUE1").alias("value"))).show()

def unequalColumnValuesTwoDF(dataFrame1,dataFrame2,key_id_col_name,key_id_value):
    chk_fst=True
    dataFrame1 = dataFrame1.where(dataFrame1[key_id_col_name] == key_id_value)
    dataFrame2 = dataFrame2.where(dataFrame2[key_id_col_name] == key_id_value)
    col_names = list(set(dataFrame1.columns).intersection(dataFrame2.columns))
    col_names.remove(key_id_col_name)
    for col_name in col_names:
        if chk_fst == True:
            df_tmp = dataFrame1.select(col(key_id_col_name).alias("KEY_ID"),col(col_name).alias("VALUE")).subtract(dataFrame2.select(col(key_id_col_name).alias("KEY_ID"),col(col_name).alias("VALUE"))).withColumn("COL_NAME",lit(col_name))
            chk_fst = False
        else:
            df_tmp = df_tmp.unionAll(dataFrame1.select(col(key_id_col_name).alias("KEY_ID"),col(col_name).alias("VALUE")).subtract(dataFrame2.select(col(key_id_col_name).alias("KEY_ID"),col(col_name).alias("VALUE"))).withColumn("COL_NAME",lit(col_name)))
    return df_tmp

res_df = unequalColumnValuesTwoDF(dataFrame1,dataFrame2,key_id_col_name,key_id_value)

res_df.show() 

   >>> dataFrame1.show()
    +---+------+------+
    | ID|VALUE1|VALUE2|
    +---+------+------+
    | A1|   500|  1005|
    | A2|   700| 10007|
    +---+------+------+

    >>> dataFrame2.show()
    +---+------+------+
    | ID|VALUE1|VALUE2|
    +---+------+------+
    | A1|   600|  1005|
    | A2|   700| 10007|
    +---+------+------+

    >>> res_df.show()
    +------+-----+--------+
    |KEY_ID|VALUE|COL_NAME|
    +------+-----+--------+
    |    A1|  500|  VALUE1|
    +------+-----+--------+
```

Please suggest any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach:

- Join the two DataFrames using the `ID` column.
- Then for each row, create a new column which contains the columns for which there is a difference.

  - Create this new column as a key-value pair map using [`pyspark.sql.functions.create_map()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map).<sup>1</sup>
  - The key for the map will be the column name.
  - Using [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when), set the value to the corresponding value in in `dataFrame1` (as it seems like that is what you want from your example) **if** there is a difference between the two DataFrames. Otherwise, we set the value to `None`.
- Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.explode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) on the map column, and filter out any rows where the difference is not null using [`pyspark.sql.functions.isnull()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.isnull).
- Select the columns you want and rename using `alias()`.

Example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
columns = [c for c in dataFrame1.columns if c != 'ID']
dataFrame1.alias('r').join(dataFrame2.alias('l'), on='ID')\
    .withColumn(
        'diffs',
        f.create_map(
            *reduce(
                list.__add__,
                [
                    [
                        f.lit(c),
                        f.when(
                            f.col('r.'+c) != f.col('l.'+c),
                            f.col('r.'+c)
                        ).otherwise(None)
                    ] 
                 for c in columns
                ]
            )
        )
    )\
    .select([f.col('ID'), f.explode('diffs')])\
    .where(~f.isnull(f.col('value')))\
    .select(
        f.col('ID').alias('KEY_ID'),
        f.col('value').alias('VALUE'),
        f.col('key').alias('COL_NAME')
    )\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+------+-----+--------+
#|KEY_ID|VALUE|COL_NAME|
#+------+-----+--------+
#|A1    |500  |VALUE1  |
#+------+-----+--------+
```

**Notes**

<sup>1</sup> The syntax `*reduce(list.__add__, [[f.lit(c), ...] for c in columns])` as the argument to `create_map()` is some python-fu that helps create the map dynamically.

`create_map()` expects an even number of arguments- it assumes that the first argument in every pair is the key and the second is the value. In order to put the arguments in that order, the list comprehension yields a list for each iteration. We reduce this list of lists into a flat list using `list.__add__`.

Finally the `*` operator is used to unpack the list.

Here is the intermediate output, which may make the logic clearer:

```python
dataFrame1.alias('r').join(dataFrame2.alias('l'), on='ID')\
    .withColumn(
        'diffs',
        f.create_map(
            *reduce(
                list.__add__,
                [
                    [
                        f.lit(c),
                        f.when(
                            f.col('r.'+c) != f.col('l.'+c),
                            f.col('r.'+c)
                        ).otherwise(None)
                     ] 
                     for c in columns
                ]
            )
        )
    )\
    .select('ID', 'diffs').show(truncate=False)
#+---+-----------------------------------+
#|ID |diffs                              |
#+---+-----------------------------------+
#|A2 |Map(VALUE1 -> null, VALUE2 -> null)|
#|A1 |Map(VALUE1 -> 500, VALUE2 -> null) |
#+---+-----------------------------------+
```